# Django Problem with FilesystemStorage.save()

Tags: django, centos7, file-system-storage

Context : Implement prod `Django` web project in Centos env.

I am trying to solve a function on file storage action that didn't work but i cant see why?... maybe a permission problem...

I have a pretty same function that work...

## The function

```
import os
def manager_file_tasks(file, archive_path):

    print(file, archive_path)
    # i got this : file.csv /MYHOME/Site_Django/media/archive_file/uploadedFiles

    tmp_archive_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'visualisation', 'UploadFiles', 'file')

    # Test if the folder archive exist
    if not os.path.exists(tmp_archive_path):
        os.makedirs(tmp_archive_path)

    print(tmp_archive_path)
    # i got this : /MYHOME/Site_Django/visualisation/UploadFiles/file

    fs = FileSystemStorage(location=tmp_archive_path)

    print(fs)
    # i got this : <django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage object at 0x7f57f622bda0>

    print(armdb_file.name, armdb_file)
    # i got this : file.csv file.csv

    print(fs.save(armdb_file.name, armdb_file))
    # NO RESULT .... :(

    filename = fs.save(armdb_file.name, armdb_file)
    print(filename)
    armdb_file = fs.path(filename)
    print(armdb_file)

    # some other stuffs are made after....
```

## Here the rights of the folder:

```
[me@web01]$ ll /MYHOME/Site_Django/visualisation/UploadFiles/
total 0
drw-r--r--. 2 apache apache 6 10 oct.  11:22 file
```

### EDIT 1

I think that i resolve a part of the problem (that encounter with SELinux)

with this command line :

```
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /MYHOME/Site_Django -R
```

### EDIT 2

The file dont exist in my tmp folder :/
Even the python code :

```
print(file.file.name)
```

return

```
/tmp/tmp1t_ahpg4.upload.csv
```

I cant read this file with that :

```
with open(file,"r") as f:

    print(f.read())
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: CSRF protection is unrelated to storage system, check this to deal with 403 error https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/

Comment: @SergeyZherevchuk yes, indeed. I resolve this problem (i had try to pass to a tmp folder inside my django project "FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, "tmp")") by comment this line in my settings.py. I still have the same error with a "Server Error (500)" with the same output.

Comment: it seems like the file is not writing in tmp.... but i dont know why....